# Sitecore: Translating the URLs, what are the solutions?

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

I am totally new with Sitecore and one of my client told me she will create her website with Sitecore. She told me that she won't be able to translate url:

From: site.com/shoes/sneakers/
To: site.com/fr/chaussures/baskets/

She said she'll only be able to do: site.com/fr/shoes/sneakers/

Anyone is aware of a solution to that problem with Sitecore so we make sure we have translated URLs in French for a maximum SEO optimization?

All the best,

Alex

Answer (score 9):

Item names can only be a single language, but you can use the Display Name instead as the URL.

To do so update the `useDisplayName` property of the linkprovider to `true`:

```
  <linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
    <providers>
      <add name="sitecore" 
           ...
           useDisplayName="true" />
    </providers>
  </linkManager>
```

The display name can be translated to multiple languages allowing you to have different URLs per language.

Also be careful with language embedding. You may want to set this to `always` so `en` is also included otherwise it will throw Sitecore when visiting a french page and the visiting an `en` URL which does not have the language embedded. Sitecore will try to resolve the item in `fr` due to the existing `lang=fr` cookie.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26929447/661447

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! So with that, I will be able to have two fully translated URLs ? www.site.com/shoes/sneakers & www.site.com/fr/chaussures/baskets/ ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There is more info here on item vs display name and the how to edit them: https://www.cmsbestpractices.com/friday-sitecore-best-practice-using-display-item-names/

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Jammy, I'll look into it !

Comment: I added some additional info from a previous question I answered that I think is important to consider.